# Calling a Method in a Repeating Timer

Tags: ios, swift, timer, notifications

I am using a timer to check the watch connectivity. I want to push a notification when the status is disconnected. My code works but it sends a notification every time the time repeats. I need the timer to keep going but only 1 notification to be sent. How would I go about this?

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 20, repeats: true) { timer in
    if WCSession.default.isReachable {
        print("Connected")
    } else {
        self.scheduleANotification()
        print("Disconnected")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `Bool` property to the class to keep track of whether the notification has been set or not. If not, send the notification and then set the flag. If set, don't send the notification.

Add this property to your class:

```
var notificationSent = false
```

Update your timer block:

```
if WCSession.default.isReachable {
    print("Connected")
} else {
    if !notificationSent {
        self.scheduleANotification()
        notificationSent = true
    }
    print("Disconnected")
}
```